# Is there a way to make socat not open the target connection until it receives a listener connection?

Tags: port-forwarding, socat

I want to run socat as a server - against a target that will go up and down intermittently (cloud microservice environment).

I want socat to listen - and open the port when it gets a listener connection.  (A socat server)

My question is: **Is there a way to make socat not open the target connection until it receives a listener connection?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default, if I understand your question. The first socket is opened and blocks in listen. Only when a connection is made will the second-named connection be attempted. You can test this. E.g. listen on port 60127 and connect to port 60128 in one shell:

```
$ socat tcp-l:60127,reuseaddr tcp:localhost:60128
```

It will block waiting.  In another shell try to connect:

```
$ telnet localhost 60127
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It fails, and the original command fails too:

```
socat[30293] E connect(3, AF=2 127.0.0.1:60128, 16): Connection refused
```

If, however, you repeat the first socat, then add another on port 60128 with:

```
$ socat tcp-l:60128,reuseaddr -
```

then the telnet will work. So, clearly the first socat does not try the second-named connection until needed.